# Adjetivo de caracterizar/caracterización

Tags: adjetivos, sinónimos, categorías-gramaticales

En una investigación literaria que estoy haciendo me refiero a **técnicas de caracterización** de la novela en cuestión muchísimo, y quiero poder mencionarlas a veces como **técnicas caracterizativas**, o tal vez **técnicas personificativas**, pero dudo que existan esos adjetivos. ¿Hay un adjetivo para expresar lo que tenga que ver con, o lo que ayuda a hacer la caracterización?

Comment: Existe caracterizador,-ra: 1. adj. Que caracteriza.

Comment: @Leo Buen punto, no me di cuenta L:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esos adjetivos que mencionas no están explicitamente recogidos en el DRAE, pero sí lo está el sufijo con el que los has construido.

> **[-ivo, va](https://dle.rae.es/-ivo)**
>
> 1. suf. Forma adjetivos y algunos sustantivos, cuya base derivativa suele ser un participio pasivo o un sustantivo latinos y, a veces, un
>    sustantivo español. Puede significar capacidad para lo significado por
>    la base o inclinación a ello. Llamativo, reflexivo, combativo,
>    defensivo, persuasivo.
> 2. suf. Existen también algunos sustantivos en -iva. Alternativa, defensiva. Por analogía con los muchos adjetivos que, formados con el
>    sufijo -ivo, terminan en -ativo o en -itivo, se han formado otros,
>    considerando estas terminaciones como nuevos sufijos. Ahorrativo,
>    factitivo.

Que yo vea, **son válidos**.

Otra cosa es que  se entienda bien lo que quieres decir. Por ejemplo si recuperamos el significado de **personificar**, a no ser que se trate de una novela como *Rebelión en la granja* de George Orwell, no parece referirse a la construcción del caracter de un personaje. Aunque puede que hagas referencia a los otros posibles significados.

> [**personificar**](https://dle.rae.es/personificar)
>
> 1. tr. Atribuir vida o acciones o cualidades propias del ser racional al irracional, o a las cosas inanimadas, incorpóreas o abstractas.
> 2. tr. **Encarnar de manera eminente una cualidad**, una idea, etc. Lutero personifica la Reforma.
> 3. tr. Concretar en alguien la representación de un suceso, idea, etc. Personificaron la Revolución francesa en Robespierre.

Como podemos apreciar abajo, caracterizar y personificar no son sinónimos a priori. A no ser que te refieras a que cada personaje encarna una cualidad que lo distingue de los demás.

> [**caracterizar**](https://dle.rae.es/caracterizar)
>
> 1. tr. Determinar los **atributos peculiares de alguien** o de algo, de modo que claramente se **distinga** de los demás