# Why is “las” sometimes appended to Spanish words?

Tags: traducción, gramática

Why are there some Spanish words like “mencionarlas” or “señalarlas”?

What does the …las at the end mean? Examples would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the translation: you can almost(?) always translate the ...las part with "them" - it refers to some other things (in the sentence, paragraph, or assumed to be known to the audience) with feminine grammatical gender (the masculine equivalent is ...los). For a single object ("it"), ...la and ...lo are used.

[Here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34620/13538) is an example on our own site:

> En una investigación literaria que estoy haciendo me refiero a técnicas de caracterización de la novela en cuestión muchísimo, **y quiero poder mencionarlas** a veces

The bolded part means "I want to be able to mention *them*" and the "them" refers to "técnicas de caracterización" (characterization techniques) earlier in the sentence.

If you're interested in the linguistics behind this: they are called [object pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_object_pronouns#Usage). They are sometimes used on their own right before the verbs in a sentence, but after verbs in infinitive form you can (or sometimes must) append them.